# What causes the Visual Studio Modules (for C++ Projects) Window to write Yes against the Optimised Column?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

What causes the Visual Studio Modules Window (for C++ Projects) to write Yes against the Optimised Column?

Until today I would have thought the answer to this question was simple, just make sure that all the optimisations are disabled.

In our main branch a colleague added a special project to bootstrap the special login code that runs for the main C++ projects to connect to the database, but in a project to be consumed by a new WPF C# App.

When the WPF App starts running special StartSession code runs within the Session DLL which causes the WPF App to be connected to the database.

If you put a breakpoint in the StartSession function then the modules window will show:

```
Name               Path                        Optimized      Symbol Status    AppDomain
============       ====                        =========      =============    =========
Session.dll        C:\somepath\Session.dll     No             Symbols Loaded   [1] DefaultDomain
Session.dll        C:\somepath\Session.dll     No             Symbols Loaded   
Session.dll        C:\somepath\Session.dll     No             Symbols Loaded
```

In the C++ Project property pages, Optimization = **Disabled** (/Od), Inline Function Expansion = **Only __inline (/Ob1)**

All the rest are set to No or Either (all in non-bold)

I needed to create a similar project for my unit testing project with Catch2, so I duplicate the folder into my branch, edit the project file to change its details to reflect the new name, add a 2nd Configuration copied from the first called "Catch2 Debug".

Then through a DLL Export I link it to my unit testing executable, but now when the module is loaded the details change

```
Name               Path                                   Optimized      Symbol Status    AppDomain
============       ====                                   =========      =============    =========
Session.dll        C:\unittestpath\UnitTest.Session.dll   Yes            Symbols Loaded   [1] DefaultDomain
Session.dll        C:\unittestpath\UnitTest.Session.dll   No             Symbols Loaded   
Session.dll        C:\unittestpath\UnitTest.Session.dll   No             Symbols Loaded
```

The reason this matters to me is that something is going wrong within the initialisation, so I need to be able to look at the contents of the variables, but when I add them to the watch window I receive the message `Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.` instead of the evaluation of the variable.

I also tried generating the project from scratch and adding the relevant source files, however still the same result

Comment: What is your solution configuration? Debug or Release. From [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-optimized-code?view=vs-2022) we can see that by default optimization is turned on in the Release configuration of the C++ program. Whether to select the corresponding configuration when modifying the "Optimization" property

Comment: It's Debug Configuration